# generic functions that operates on collections in scala

Tags: scala, collections

This seems like a simple question that I was sure have been asked before, but couldn't find what I was looking for.

How can one write a function that takes a collection as an argument (or anything that can be treated as a collection), perform some operations on it, and return a collection of the same type?

e.g:

```
scala> def foo[Repr <% Traversable[String]](repr: Repr) = repr.map(_.size)
foo: [Repr](repr: Repr)(implicit evidence$1: Repr => Traversable[String])Traversable[Int]
```

this works ok on some collections:

```
scala> foo(Vector("Hello","World"))
res0: Traversable[Int] = Vector(5, 5)
```

but surprising when I tried on other collections (e.g. `Option`):

```
scala> foo(Some("HelloWorld"))
res1: Traversable[Int] = List(10)
```

a small problem is the return type `Traversable`, which ideally would be the type of whatever was given to the method. the bigger problem is the actual implementation type: an `Option` became a `List`.
it gets even worse, when tried on classes (that behaves like collections) but have no implicit in scope for them. e.g: `Try`:

```
scala> import scala.util._
import scala.util._

scala> foo(Success("HelloWorld"))
<console>:12: error: No implicit view available from scala.util.Success[String] => Traversable[String].
              foo(Success("HelloWorld"))
                 ^
```

So, is there a way, to write a generic function, that when given a "collection like" argument, can operate on it's elements and return the correct type?

ideally, I would like to use it on anything (even `Future`, and `Try`) , but for my specific usage, I can do with just real collections & `Option`.

#### EDIT:

to illustrate a possible solution, (which forces me to copy&paste code, and so, is not what i'm looking for) is to simply write both functions without view bounds:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def foo[Repr <: Traversable[String]](repr: Repr) = repr.map(_.size)
def foo(repr: Option[String]) = repr.map(_.size)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

foo: [Repr <: Traversable[String]](repr: Repr)Traversable[Int] <and> (repr: Option[String])Option[Int]
foo: [Repr <: Traversable[String]](repr: Repr)Traversable[Int] <and> (repr: Option[String])Option[Int]

scala> foo(Vector("bar"))
res2: Traversable[Int] = Vector(3)

scala> foo(Some("bar"))
res3: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

Comment: Not all collections can support all possible operations so in general you can't write something to support an arbitrary operation. Are there any constraints on the kinds of operation you need?

Comment: Specifically i have just a `map` invokation. But if there is a way to do it more generic and allow other operations like `flatMap` or `filter`, I'd like to know how.

Comment: I:m really not sure what you're after. Again, not all collections support all operations. So you need to constrain the type somehow. Are you asking to be able to define an operation that works on, say, all collection types that support `flatMap`? Or something else?

Comment: In other words, what do you mean as "treated as a collection" in  "anything that can be treated as a collection"?

Comment: what implementation return type do you consider proper for foo(Option[T]) ?

Comment: @Paul I'm after not writing some method more than once. in the context of the above example, I could have written it using 2 methods (editing the question to show how). I believe it is achievable with macros, but have no prior knowledge with macros, and wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: @ka4eli an `Option[T]` :)

Comment: So in the updated example from your question, you want to support any type that has a `map` method, and  where the elements mapped over  are Strings?

Comment: @Paul that's right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of mapping is represented by functors. One way to easily provide functor implementations for common classes is to use the scalaz library:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds
import scalaz.Functor
import scalaz.Scalaz._

def foo[El <: String, Coll[_]](repr: Coll[El])(implicit ev: Functor[Coll]) =
    repr.map(_.size)
```

Now, this just works for `List`, `Vector` and `Future`:

```
scala> foo(Vector("Hello","World"))
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(5, 5)

scala> foo(List("Hello","World"))
res2: List[Int] = List(5, 5)

scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
scala> foo(Future("HelloWorld")) andThen PartialFunction(println(_))

Success(10)
```

Using it with `Some` is a bit of a problem, because only `Option` has a `Functor` implementation, not `Some`:

```
scala> foo(Some("HelloWorld"))
<console>:12: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: scalaz.Functor[Some]
              foo(Some("HelloWorld"))
                 ^
```

So you have to provide `Option` instead of `Some` to `foo`:

```
scala> foo(Some("HelloWorld"): Option[String])
res3: Option[Int] = Some(10)

scala> foo(Option("HelloWorld"))
res4: Option[Int] = Some(10)

scala> foo("HelloWorld".some) // This is from scalaz
res5: Option[Int] = Some(10)
```

And scalaz doesn't have any typeclass implementations for `Try`, so if you want to use `Functor` with `Try`, you'll have to provide the implementation yourself:

```
import scala.util.Try
import scalaz.Functor

implicit object TryIsFunctor extends Functor[Try] {
  def map[A, B](fa: Try[A])(f: A => B): Try[B] = fa map f
}
```

Then `foo` will work with `Try`, but similar to `Option`, the argument should have the type `Try`, instead of `Success` or `Failure`:

```
scala> foo(Try("HelloWorld"))
res9: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(10)
```

Also, I believe, there are no `Functor` implementations in scalaz for more general collection types, like `Iterable` or `Seq`.

Out of the common higher-order functions `Functor` only supports `map`. So to use `flatMap` and `filter` you have to provide different typeclasses instead of `Functor`. For example, `scalaz.Monad` supports `map` and `flatMap`, and `scalaz.MonadPlus` supports `map`, `flatMap` and `filter`.

And if you don't want to use scalaz, you'd probably have to make something very similar yourself with typeclasses, to get a good result type instead of `Traversable`. For example, using `CanBuildFrom` from the standard library.

Comment: Thank you. since scalaz is... well... scalaz, I prefer not to add it to the project. I admit I'm not too familiar with it, but I understand adding it may cause dramatic rise in compilation time. can you point me to the right direction on how to use `CanBuildFrom` to achieve a similar result?

Comment: Importing all of scalaz will dramatically increase compilation time for those files that import it (if they use implicits), but if you restrict yourself to the specific imports you need then the impact should be no different from `CanBuildFrom`. Note that you can get a `Functor[Try]` instance by depending on scalaz-outlaws.

Answer (score 2):

I do think Kolmar is right about the general problem, but Scala does support duck-typing, so you can do this:

```
def foo[T[V]](duck: {def map[U](value: String=>U): T[_]}) ={
   duck.map(_.size)
}

foo(Vector("bar")).toVector                         //> res0: Vector[_$2] = List(3)
foo(Some("bar"))                                  //> res1: Option[_$2] = Some(3)
```

(toVector just to force the eval of the iterator that otherwise results)

Comment: that's cool! but the return types & actual instances don't always work out as expected. `foo(Some("bar"))` yields an `Option[Any]` instead of an `Option[Int]`, and `foo(Vector("bar"))` yields `TraversableOnce[Any]` backed by an iterator instead of `Vector[Int]`.

Comment: still, what you showed is cool, and thanks for that. I'm beginning to think that may be what I'm after isn't possible, or at list isn't that simple as I thought...

Comment: Note that the argument needs to have a `map` method with exactly the same signature, which is not the case of every conceivable `map` method. It works for `Option` because its `map` method has that exact signature. It also works for any `TraversableOnce`, even though for most -- such as for `List` -- the `map` method does not have the same signature. It still works here because it implicitly converts to `TraversableOnce.MonadOps`, where the `map` method **does** have the required signature. Now, you can find cases where it just won't work, such as for `Future`.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles, thanks for the observations, which I agree with. But I think the OP's problem also requires that the map method has the exactly the same signature (in as much as I understand his question which I don't think I do completely)

Comment: " Now, you can find cases where it just won't work, such as for Future. " and we're back to the question 'what does the OP mean by "anything that can be treated as a collection"'.  For me, the canonical "function that takes a collection as an argument [...], perform some operations on it, and return a collection of the same type" _is_ `map` (or `flatMap`)

Comment: Well no, OP's problem does not necessarily *require* that the `map` method has exactly the same signature, as evidenced by the type class-based solution proposed by Kolmar (where the the different type class 
instances can under the hood call any `map` method, or even any method irrespective of their name). In addition, `map` has special support in scala in the sense that it is transparently called by the compiler when 
doing for comprehension, and in this case the signature of the `map` method does not matter so long as it is callable with a single argument.

Comment: Indeed the signature can have additional arguments with default values, or implicit arguments, or it can be generic or not, all that does not matter so long as it fits.
So the compiler is able to handle `map` (in for comprehensions) in the most general sense (that is, with a very loose defintion of what `map` is), which seems to also be the case of 
In contrast, the definition of `map` in your code is much stricter so I think it's worth pointing that difference.

Comment: Yep. And the right way of doing this (in Scala) is a typeclass with implicits, I think. Which does involve a small amount of duplication, but not much